# How to abort a react-native-git-upgrade?

Tags: git, react-native

I just tried running [`react-native-git-upgrade`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html#upgrade-based-on-git), which resulted in a couple of merge conflicts:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy-app kurtpeek$ react-native-git-upgrade
git-upgrade info Check for updates 
git-upgrade info Using yarn 1.3.2 
git-upgrade info Read package.json files 
git-upgrade info Check declared version 
git-upgrade info Check matching versions 
git-upgrade info Check React peer dependency 
git-upgrade info Check that Git is installed 
git-upgrade info Get information from NPM registry 
git-upgrade info Upgrading to React Native 0.54.0, React ^16.3.0-alpha.1 
git-upgrade info Setup temporary working directory 
git-upgrade info Configure Git environment 
git-upgrade info Init Git repository 
git-upgrade info Add all files to commit 
git-upgrade info Commit current project sources 
git-upgrade info Create a tag before updating sources 
git-upgrade info Generate old version template 
git-upgrade info Add updated files to commit 
git-upgrade info Commit old version template 
git-upgrade info Install the new version 
warning " > babel-jest@21.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "babel-core@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0-alpha || ^7.0.0-beta || ^7.0.0".
warning "react-native > metro > @babel/plugin-check-constants@7.0.0-beta.38" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@7.0.0-beta.38".
git-upgrade info Generate new version template 
git-upgrade info Add updated files to commit 
git-upgrade info Commit new version template 
git-upgrade info Generate the patch between the 2 versions 
git-upgrade info Save the patch in temp directory 
git-upgrade info Reset the 2 temporary commits 
git-upgrade info Apply the patch 
error: patch failed: .flowconfig:51
Falling back to three-way merge...
Applied patch to '.flowconfig' with conflicts.
error: patch failed: android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:1
Falling back to three-way merge...
Applied patch to 'android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' with conflicts.
U .flowconfig
U android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
git-upgrade WARN The upgrade process succeeded but there might be conflicts to be resolved. See above for the list of files that have merge conflicts. 
git-upgrade info Upgrade done
```

After inspecting the merge conflicts, on second thoughts, I'd like to abort the upgrade. How would I do this? Do I simply

```
git reset --hard
```

following [Rollback to last git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965639/rollback-to-last-git-commit)?